# Angular CSS Accordion Heading

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an accordion that needs to change the color of it's heading background based on a value passed to it. e.g. red or green.
In the example below I have a header row for each store name. If a store is out of business, I need to flag the background of the heading as red instead of green. I am not able to get this to work.

```
   <accordion id="accordion1" close-others="true">
  <accordion-group is-open="isopen"  ng-repeat="store in stores">
       <accordion-heading class="container-fluid heading-highlight">
       {{store.StoreName}}
       </accordion-heading>
    <form name="form">
      <div class="form-row" ng-repeat="record in store.records">
       <table>
          <tr ng-formfield></tr>  //dynamic form directive
       </table>
     </div>
    </form>
  </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

I tried using the following directive but nothing works no matter what changes I make.

```
app.directive('headingHighlight', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            $scope.$watch(element.children(), function () {
                var children = element.children('.panel-heading');
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

                        angular.element(children[i]).css('background', 'red');

                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

working directive below:

```
app.directive('headingHighlight', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                scope.$watch(element, function () {        
                    if (scope.color.Highlight != null) {
                            var panelhead = element.children('.panel-heading');
                            panelhead.css({
                                'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,' + scope.color.Highlight +
                                ' 0%,  #e8e8e8 100%)', 'background-repeat': 'repeat-x', 'height': '85px;'
                            });
                        }

                });

            }
        };
    });
```